# Chained interpolation of static string doesn't work as expected

Tags: c#, string, string-interpolation

I was using a code like this:

```
public static class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        Console.WriteLine(hello);
    }

    internal static readonly string hello = $"hola {name} {num}";
    internal static readonly string name  = $"Juan {num}";
    public const int num = 4;
}
```

In this case, when I got the value of hello it returned to me "hola 4", so it seems that there is a problem when interpolate another string that use interpolation.
My expected behaviour is "hola Juan 4 4" or if the language doesn't support this kind of chained interpolation an error in compilation time.

Does anybody know why C# gets this behaviour?

Comment: Those are just string fields, there's no kind of chaining. The *interpolation expressions* refer to the fields, not each other, so there's no kind of chaining there either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Static fields are initialized in the order that they're declared. So what happens is:

1. Initially, `hello` and `name` are both `null`. `num` is a const.
2. `hello` is initialized. `name` is still `null`. However, `num` is a const, so that gets correctly substituted. `hello` has the value `"hola   4"`
3. `name` is initialized.

---

Why does the fact that `num` is a const make a difference? Remember that the value of a const is subtituted directly into the places that it's used, by the compiler at compile-time. So if you look at what the compiler generates, you see:

```
public static class Program
{
    internal static readonly string hello = string.Format("hola {0} {1}", name, 4);

    internal static readonly string name = string.Format("Juan {0}", 4);

    public const int num = 4;

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(hello);
    }
}
```

(Courtesy of [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABATARgLABQ2AzAAQDehp1p2WFVNTGOAnABQAWMANjxAEoA3I2oBfQqNIBLAHYAXGFFkBDHrRxJSsFQBMIsngE8NABlLc+EUgF5SAEgBEnCDxUVVAWxhiPAV08xRxECJjlFZTUNLR19QxMWcy8YajsnACk/FVl/QOCpDDJIWQBneRkFUlkA21IUELEgA==))

Notice how the value of the const is compiled into the places it's used.

---

When you have static fields that depend on each other, you either need to be very careful with the order that they're declared, or it's normally safer (and more readable!) to just use a static constructor:

```
public static class Program {
    static Program() {
        name = $"Juan {num}";
        hello = $"hola {name} {num}";
    }

    public static void Main() {
        Console.WriteLine(hello);
    }

    internal static readonly string hello;
    internal static readonly string name;
    public const int num = 4;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can switch the positions of `hello` and `name` like,

```
internal static readonly string name = $"Juan {num}";
internal static readonly string hello = $"hola {name} {num}";
```

> Because when `hello` is assigning, the `name` is not assigned yet.

After reorder `name` and `hello`, it will print as you want

> Prints => "hola Juan 4 4"